# Overlay second image on top of image within ImageViewTouch on Android

Tags: android, imageview

I'm having a hard time believing this isn't possible. I have a map in an [`ImageViewTouch`](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) view, and I'm trying to add a "You Are Here" image on the image that I move (within the map image) based on the user's location.

When the user pans around on the map, I'd like the You Are Here to pan too by being inside the `ImageViewTouch`. (Ideally I'd like it to scale with zooming too, but I'll take what I can get!)

I've considered using `Canvas` to create a new `Bitmap` every time the user's location changes, but considering the map is large, it wouldn't be very performant.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Instead of using `Canvas` and `Bitmap` which are slower and cause issues, I was able to use `LayerDrawable`. In case this helps anyone in the future, here's my code.

```
public void updateYouAreHere(@Nullable MapLocation location, boolean initial){

    Resources resources = getResources();
    Drawable drawable;

    if (location == null){
        drawable = MiscUtil.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.map_image);
    }else{

        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[]{
                MiscUtil.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.map_image),
                MiscUtil.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.you_are_here)
        };
        mapDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

        final int iconWidth = 50;
        final int iconHeight = 86;
        mapDrawable.setLayerInset(1, location.x, location.y,
                (int)(Globals.Map.MapWidth) - location.x - iconWidth, (int)(Globals.Map.MapHeight) - location.y - iconHeight);
        drawable = mapDrawable;
    }

    if (!initial) {
        Matrix currentPosition = mapScrollView.getDisplayMatrix();
        float minScale = mapScrollView.getMinScale();
        float maxScale = mapScrollView.getMaxScale();
        mapScrollView.setImageDrawable(drawable, currentPosition, minScale, maxScale);
    }else{
        mapScrollView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}

private class MapLocation {

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public MapLocation(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

Also, `MiscUtil.getDrawable` is just a wrapper that calls the appropriate `getResources().getDrawable()` function based on SDK version.